# Adding html break to each line in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, line-breaks, web-crawler

What I basically have here is a short ruby script (I just started learning) and the purpose of it is to spider-crawl a website and return all the links it finds.

```
@sites = Array.new
Anemone.crawl("http://www.nemecisco.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
    puts page.url
    @sites<<page.url+""  #heres where i add something to give it a line break i think
  end
  anemone.after_crawl { puts @sites }
end
end
```

It does this fine, however when Its being outputted to the HTML, they are all clustered together as it trys to jam them on the one line.
The HTML is just the array inside the ruby script tag.

```
<%= @sites %>
```

You may notice that the array is composed of the pages name + something else. I figured a break tag would be enough but Ruby doesn't like this and gives a bad URI exception.

Has anyone any ideas on how to put a line break after each site statement. In the HTML declaration? in the array? Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the safest thing to do is to do it manually in the ERB:

```
<% @sites.each do |site| %>
    <%= site %><br>
<% end %>
```

Or in Rails 2:

```
<% @sites.each do |site| %>
    <%=h site %><br>
<% end %>
```

This way you don't have to worry about possible HTML issues the `@sites` entries.

Comment: I wasn't thrilled about using ruby code within the view itself but this worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @overtone: You're dealing with formatting so it is the view's problem, putting that anywhere else would pollute the rest of your code with HTML concerns that only the view should care about.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to output an array, it's joining them with a newline `\n` instead of an HTML break. You can force an HTML break by joining with a `br` tag:

```
<%= @sites.join("<br />") %>
```

In Rails 3, you may need to turn off escaping:

```
<%= raw(@sites.join("<br />")) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Amemone, but I'm assuming `page.url` returns an instance of the `URI` class.  You need to convert the url to a string (`page.url.to_s`) before appending to it.

I would probably leave the urls as URI instances though, and format them when I print.  Change your `after_crawl` method to be `{ puts @sites.join("\n") }` (the `URI` instances will be converted to strings automatically).

Comment: Wasn't sure if you were outputting html or text.  Change the `\n` to `<br>` if you're doing HTML.